# How to read headers of GDF file using mne.io.read_raw_gdf()?

Tags: python, signal-processing, mne-python

I am trying to read EEG header and data from a .gdf file using Python 3.

I tried and failed to install [Biosig](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biosig/files/BioSig%20for%20Python/) tool that offers this functionality according to documentation:

```
import biosig
import json
header=json.loads(biosig.header("file_eeg.gdf"))
data=biosig.data("file_eeg.gdf")
```

But it seems not to be working on Python 3/Ubuntu 20.04 environment.

Since I can successfully read the raw EEG data using [mne](https://mne.tools/stable/) with Python 3:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import mne

raw = mne.io.read_raw_gdf("file_eeg.gdf")
```

I need to find a way to access also the header data of the .gdf file using mne.

Do you have any suggestions on how to read and access both header and eeg data of a .gdf file using mne in Python 3?

Also, if you have any alternative solutions feel free to share!

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: EDIT: I solved it by installing Biosig  properly using this: https://pypi.org/project/Biosig/
but still did not found a way to read header data using MNE.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting events form header this works fine to me.

```
events_A, event_id_A = mne.events_from_annotations(raw)
```